# How to display desired data according to the given rule?

Tags: excel-formula

How can I display desired data "Description" according to its given specification? I got to fill up yellow boxes. Formula only

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Different approach would be:
`=INDEX(K:K,AGGREGATE(15,6,(SEARCH($J$5:$J$8,F5)>0)*ROW($J$5:$J$8),1))`
Enter with `ctrl+shift+enter` in Excel prior to Office 365.

This may come in handy if you change your index list and don't want to change all `IF` conditions.

Note that if text of the list is found twice it'll return the first match only.

PS please note your system code in column F is off compared to the ID in column B